# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profilesInfoModel does not exist. // RegisterController.php

Tags: laravel

what i need is to save some data besides creating the user, here is what I've been trying to do in my `RegisterController.php` :

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if (isset($data['checkbox'])) {
        $type = 1;
        $available = 1;
    } else {
        $type = 0;
        $available = 0;
    }

     $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'type' => $type,
        'available' => $available,
        'company' => $data['company'],
        'job' => $data['job'],
    ]);

    $user->profilesInfoModel()->create([
        'bio' => $data['bio'],
        'site' => $data['site'],
        'location' => $data['location'],
        'education' => $data['education'],
    ]);

    return $user->with('profilesInfoModel');


}
```

The User.php (`Model`) has a `one to one` relationship with `profilesInfoModel` (yes, i know i should change the name of the model to make it more comfortable).

But after trying to register a user... i get this error message: `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profilesInfoModel does not exist.`

What is actually going on?

Comment: can you add your model code as well for both models profile and user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship should be like this

User Model

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProfileInfo::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Assuming you have `ProfileInfo` as Profile model and it has `user_id` as foreign key references `users` table `id` field

Now you can create profile from `$user` like this

```
$user->profile()->create([
    'bio' => $data['bio'],
    'site' => $data['site'],
    'location' => $data['location'],
    'education' => $data['education'],
]);

$user->load('profile'); //lazy eager load

return $user;
```

Answer (score 0):

1.in App\Model\User

```
public function profilesInfoModel()
{
    return $this->hasOne(App\Model\User);
}
```

2.to call

```
use App\Model\User
```

in RegisterController